# I'm wodering if this statement is provable in logic $ \lnot \alpha \to \lnot \lnot \lnot \alpha ) $

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, natural-deduction

I've encountered this statement in my final exam

$$ \lnot  \alpha \to \lnot \lnot \lnot  \alpha ) $$

there was no open parenthesis and from what I know this is invalid (not a well-formed formula) so I just put NWFF in the answer sheet.

I'm I missing something? Can it be proved in natural deduction or sequent calculus ?

EDIT : to those who says that this is probably a typo on the exam , no it's not a typo because I've seen the same statement in the exam of the last year !

Comment: Indeed it is not a well formed formula. If you give the benefit of the doubt to the asker and assume there was a typo, the statement can be derived using standard negation introduction.

Comment: I wonder why you did not just ask whether this was a typo _during the exam_ (at least where I live, students have the right to ask such questions, and yes, silly typos do happen even in exams). Would seem more productive than to come to MSE afterwards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's probably just a typo in the exam.

Anyway note that it would never be a well-formed formula (wff) anyway as long as $\alpha$ plays the role of a *metavariable*. If you still want a demonstration that any instance of this *formula schema* is not a wff, it goes like this:

**Definition (well-formed formula)**

- $\alpha$ is a wff if $\alpha$ is atomic
- $(\neg\alpha)$ is a wff if $\alpha$ is a wff
- $(\alpha \rightarrow \beta)$ is a wff if $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are wff

Therefore, by making explict the omitted parenthesis in the OP's formula we have
$$((¬α)→(¬(¬(¬α))))\color{red}{)}$$

Where any instance of it is not a wff, since it would have one additional occurrence of parenthesis - by the way, it's always a good exercise to show the number of parenthesis of a wff is always even (prove it)

---

**The proof schema**

If there's any doubt about how to prove any instance of the (well-formed) formula schema:
$$¬α→¬¬¬α$$
(where I omit the parenthesis) in natural deduction it goes like this:

> 1. $\neg\alpha$, Hypothesis
>
> > 2. $\neg(\neg\alpha)$, Hypothesis
> > 3. $\neg\alpha \wedge \neg(\neg\alpha)$, 1,2, $\wedge$-Introduction
>
> 4. $\neg(\neg(\neg\alpha))$, 1-3, $\neg$-Introduction
> 5. $\neg\alpha \rightarrow \neg(\neg(\neg\alpha))$, 1-4, $\rightarrow$-Introduction

Note that this is not a proof, but only a proof schema.